# Decomposition of differential form on a globally-hyperbolic manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be Lorentzian manifold of the form

$$M=I\times \Sigma,\quad\quad g=-dt^{2}+h_{t}$$

where $\Sigma$ is a spacelike hypersurface and $h_{t}$ is a Riemannian metric on $\Sigma$ for every $t\in I$. Now, I have seen the following claim:

> $\alpha\in\Omega^{k}(M)$ can be written as $\alpha=(\partial_{t}\lrcorner \alpha)\wedge dt+i^{\ast}_{\Sigma}\alpha$, where $i_{\Sigma}:\Sigma\to M$ denotes the embedding.

**My question is:** Is $i_{\Sigma}^{\ast}\alpha$ above correct?

Lets take $\alpha\in\Omega^{k}(M)$. Then, in coordinates, we have that (indiced of $\Sigma$ denoted by $i\in \{1,\dots,d\}$ and indices of $M$ by $\mu\in\{0,\dots,d\}$):

$$\alpha=\frac{1}{k!}\alpha_{\mu_{1}\dots\mu_{k}}dx^{\mu_{1}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{\mu_{k}}=\underbrace{\bigg (\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\alpha_{0i_{2}\dots i_{k}}dx^{i_{2}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_{k}}\bigg)}_{=\partial_{t}\lrcorner\alpha\in\Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}\bigwedge^{k-1}T^{\ast}\Sigma)}\wedge dt + \underbrace{\frac{1}{k!}\alpha_{i_{1}\dots i_{k}}dx^{i_{1}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_{k}}}_{\in\Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}\bigwedge^{k}T^{\ast}\Sigma)}$$

which gives a similar decomposition as above, i.e. $\alpha=(\partial_{t}\lrcorner\alpha)\wedge dt+\alpha_{\Sigma}$ where $\alpha_{\Sigma}$ is a "time-dependent $k$-form on $\Sigma$", i.e. $\alpha_{\Sigma}\in\Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}\bigwedge^{k}T^{\ast}\Sigma)$ with $\mathrm{pr}:\mathbb{R}\times\Sigma\to\Sigma$. However, $\alpha_{\Sigma}$ is not the same as $i_{\Sigma}^{\ast}\alpha$, as the latter is equivalent to $\alpha_{\Sigma}\vert_{\Sigma}$, i.e. its not time-dependent. So, it seems to be me that the above decomposition is wrong, i.e. it should rather be $\alpha=(\partial_{t}\lrcorner \alpha)\wedge dt+\alpha_{\Sigma}$ where $\alpha_{\Sigma}$ is the time-dependent $k$-form on $\Sigma$ as defined above.

Comment: The general structure of the formula cannot be correct either, since the first summand is a $k$-Form and not a $k+1$-Form.

Comment: There was a typo, fixed it @AndreasCap .

Comment: @B.Hueber Is there also a type when you write $\alpha$? The first term appears to be the wedge product of a $k$ form and a $1$-form.

Also, who are that authors / which paper/book is this from?

Comment: @GeoffreySangston I think it shluld be fine. $\partial_{t}\lrcorner\alpha$ is a  $(k-1)$-form and $d t$ a $1$-form. It is taken from some lecture notes, which I am not sure whether I am allowed to share.

Comment: That's right, but $dx^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}$ looks like a wedge product of $k$ terms.

Comment: @GeoffreySangston a yes, indeed. let me fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Here, $\Sigma$ is assumed to be a level set of the function $t$.

Comment: @Deane yes, $\Sigma=t^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Then $\alpha$ restricted to $\Sigma$ has no dependence on $t$.

Comment: @Deane Exactly, thats my point.

Comment: @Deane The authors essentially claim that $\alpha=(\partial_{t}\lrcorner\alpha)\wedge d t+i_{\Sigma}^{\ast}\alpha$, but this cannot be true, precisely since $i_{\Sigma}^{\ast}\alpha$ does not dependent on time. Rather $i^{\ast}_{\Sigma}\alpha$ should be replaced by the form $\alpha_{\Sigma}$ defined locally by $\alpha_{i_{1}\dots i_{k}}$, i.e. $\alpha$ restricted only to indices $i_{1},\dots,i_{k}\neq 0$, which is a *time-dependent* form on $\Sigma$.

Comment: @Deane see the edit of my question, maybe its clearer now.

Comment: Perhaps you could define $\alpha_{\Sigma}$, perhaps with respect to coordinates. For me, $\alpha_\Sigma$ *is* $i_\Sigma^*\alpha$. Either way, it is the restriction of $\alpha$ to $\Sigma$, which means setting $t = 0$, which also implies $dt = 0$. The only other definition of the restriction of $\alpha$ that I can think of is to restrict $\alpha$ to be a section of the pullback bundle $i_\Sigma^*T^*M$, but it's clear that is not what it meant here.

Comment: @Deane no, the relation is $\alpha_{\Sigma}\vert_{\Sigma}=i_{\Sigma}^{\ast}\alpha$. So the difference is that $\alpha_{\Sigma}$ depends on time while $i_{\Sigma}^{\ast}\alpha$ doesnt.

Comment: Ok. I see your point. You’re correct